# Anchor #Tag moves entire page up when div clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing a problem with `#tag`. I have 6 `div` on the page. Each `div` has some 9 `div` which have hidden content and displayed when their related thumbnails are clicked.The problem is that entire page moves up when thumbnail of the 3 - 4 or 5 - 6 `div` are clicked. I have `div` in below order

```
<br> 1  2 <br>
3 4<br>
5 6<br>
```

Please can somebody answer what may be the issue.

Comment: Please, provide more information (html, css and javascript).

Comment: are u doing any actions on click of 'a' tag

Comment: Yes on click of each thumbnail the active div is hidden and the clicked one is displayed

Comment: when `#tag` is not  found (i mean there is no element in DOM with ID=tag) then the page will move to the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using click event on anchor tag, give `href` as `href="#"`. If you don't mention `href`, page will scrolled to top on click.

Comment: I have mentioned href="#"

Answer (score 0):

try it
It won't scroll your page to top.

```
href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="yourFunction();"
```

Answer (score 0):

`#tage` is you used for to single page link.
So if there is no id found in your page then it will jump to body tag so use javascript instead of using # like bellow.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ></>
```